# fzip: zipping a file takes full memory

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm using fzip to zip the contents of a folder. The folder contains 4 files of 500MB, the problem is that this uses all of my computers memory. Is there a way to prevent this? And lock the memory at 20% or something?

this is my code:

```
public function packageFileParser(filesToZip:Array):void {
            for (var i:uint = 0; i < filesToZip.length; i++) {
                if (filesToZip[i]["isDirectory"] == true) {
                    packageFileParser(filesToZip[i].getDirectoryListing());
                } else {
                    if (filesToZip[i]["isHidden"] == false) {
                        var byteLoader:UrlURLLoader = new UrlURLLoader();
                        byteLoader.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.BINARY;
                        byteLoader.addEventListener (flash.events.Event.COMPLETE, urlLoaderCompleteHandler);
                        var fileRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest ("/"+filesToZip[i]["nativePath"]);
                        byteLoader.load (fileRequest);  
                    }
                }
            }
        }


        private function urlLoaderCompleteHandler(event:flash.events.Event):void {
            var saveZip : Function = function(zip : FZip) : void {
                var out : ByteArray = new ByteArray();
                zip.serialize(out);

                var fs : FileStream = new FileStream;
                targetFile = File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath(zipName);
                fs.open(targetFile, FileMode.WRITE);
                fs.writeBytes(out);
                out.clear();
                fs.close();
            };
            var fullpath:String = event.target.urlRequest.url;
            var filename:String = fullpath.substr(fullpath.lastIndexOf("/")+1,fullpath.length);
            var filepath:String = fullpath.substr(0,fullpath.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
            filepath = filepath.split("/Users/Thibaut/Desktop/testfolder").join("");
            zip.addFile(filepath+filename, event.target.data);
            saveZip(zip);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, FZip library creates entire archive in memory and then saves it to disk. There's nothing you can do except to change library. Try **airxzip** from coltware, it served me well (I think there was no big memory loads even on large archives, because they were flushed to disk while adding files to them.)
Also, if you're using AIR capabilities (FileStream class), you should add "air" tag to the question, it changes a lot compared to plain AS3.